# WHILE loop containing insert from linked server gets progressivly slower

Tags: sql, while-loop, linked-server

This is driving me crazy. i have a WHILE loop that grabs 1 row from a linked server and drops it into a local table. The logic works fine but the loop slows down and down the more rows that are processed.

```
SELECT @max_id = MAX(id), @min_id = MIN(id)
FROM #ids
    WHILE @min_id <= @max_id
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'SELECT row1, row2, row3 FROM [Linked Server Table]'

        INSERT INTO [Local Table]
        (row1 ,row2, row3)
        EXEC(@sql)

        SELECT @min_id = MIN(id)
        FROM #id
        WHERE id > @min_id
    END
```

It feels like something is building up in memory and slowing it down but i don't know what.

So far i have tried:-

Turning the INSERT into an SP

Adding a CHECKPOINT for every 100 rows

Changing the Recovery Model to Simple

Inserting the linked server rows to a temp table or table variable

There are no indexes on the local table apart from PK.
The linked server is an Atomix database.

Can anyone suggest any reason why this would be getting slower and slower?

S

Comment: Why are you using loops **at all**?

Comment: Rewrite this as a single SQL statement! Don't use slow-by-slow (row-by-row) processing!

Comment: which version of sql server are you using? also, it seems like the list of ids are meaningless here. how are you using them?

Comment: OK, the code is more complex than i've submitted, the data i'm grabbing from the Atomix database is in multiple tables, the suffix of the table is passed from the temp table i'm looping over.

Comment: @user1783269 we need more information.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but writing it in a single statement will allow SQL Server to optimize its execution. In its current form you are "shoehorning" it into doing things a certain way.

Comment: Exactly: best case, one round trip to get all data from the remote server. Single SQL statements can be orders of magnitude faster than doing things row-by-row.

Comment: OK, the code is more complex than i've submitted, the data i'm grabbing from the Atomix database is in multiple tables, the suffix of the table is passed from the temp table i'm looping over. Basically i am forced to use loops, i've tried attacking this from one statement but just doesn't work. Using SQL Server 2008 Standard. The id is the PK of the temp table i'm looping over, it contains flags for what to do with the record and where it resides in the linker servers schemata.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, it can be the matter of quality in transmitting network traffic between your database engine and the remote linked server. I strongly recommend you to limit the select clause from linked server using `"TOP"` clause which means smaller packages retrieving from the network so the bad quality gonna be less effective on the speed.

Also as far as my experience says, `"WHILE"` is naturaly slow itself. Doing data modification in a while means you put the engine to start a transaction before the insert, after that, doing the insert and transfer data, finally close the transaction and release all the allocated resources. You force the engine to not to wait between closing and the beginning of the operation. I should suggest you to use `"WAIT FOR DELAY"` with value of some milliseconds putting before end of while, after insert completed, it will not take the engine's breath away!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mohammed. The linked server query is always grabbing just one record. I added a WAITFOR delay as you suggested and this does reduce the effect however it does still slow down as it goes. Out of 1000 records the first 100 processes in 1:05 secs, the final 100 in 1:25secs. I realise the WHILE is slow in general but sometimes it is the only option available. Can you think of any other reason why this would be slowing down progressivly?

Comment: However the result would be one record everytime, please put the TOP clause in your select anyway. It will force the code not to look for another record in the datasource, no matter it does exists or not. I think at this step, you should do some analysing about the situation. If the linked server is SQL Server too, use some profiling tools like profiler.

Comment: As you should know, linked servers are all based on ODBC drivers (as all the Microsoft things are!) so you can use the Performance Monitor to analyse the status of the transmission in the drivers. If I were you, I would check the steps one by one. First check for a local linked server, then for network transmission between the servers, after all query execution state on the linked server host. Execute query directly on server and see what the results would be there. Let me know if you had any problems. Cheers

Comment: i can't use TOP as it is not in the atomox syntax. the equivelant command for informix (what atomix is derived from) is FIRST but this isn't recognised either. i will try you other suggestions however

Comment: Do modifications based on the knowledge you earned from the profiling tools. I hope my informations helped you. Cheers